# Jenkins performance with 1000+ nodes - own device farm

Tags: testing, jenkins, device, server-farm

Hi i have a question according to Jenkins.

I want to create my own device farm with it.

For first simply example there will be 5, 6 nodes and i know that Jenkins will work perfectly with them.

But what if there will be 1000+ nodes? It is even possible? Are there another solution like Jenkins but for much much devices and nodes?

I fount aws-device-farm but i want my solution for that.

Target is to connect lot of devices with labels, and run tests on them, then get a result.